# Xcode - Run Simulator with older iOS Version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

Hey I have done a lot of looking around and seen many answers for how to do this in older versions of Xcode, but they don't seem to aplly to Xcode 6. So how can I run an older version of iOS in the simulator with Xcode 6.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you talking about how to run iOS 7?

Comment: This also works on Xcode 7.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the Downloads pane of Xcode's Preferences, download the iOS 7 or 7.1 simulator.

After it is downloaded, go to the Devices window (Window -> Devices) and click the Plus button to make a new simulated device with the system version you want. For example you might decide to make an iPhone 4s that's running iOS 7.

Now you'll be able to choose that device/system as the destination when you build and run.

Comment: Took a while to find an answer as simple as this.

Answer (score 31):

Please note that matt's solution is not available on new version of OS X (El Capitan). Here are all the available Simulators:

[image]