# Is iOS 10.2.1 Available For Use As a Simulator In XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I had XCode 8.2.1 and could not find an option to get the iOS 10.2.1 SDK as a simulator, it only went up to 10.2.

I installed XCode 8.3, beta 5 and now I see iOS 10.3 as an option, but still no option to to create a simulator running 10.2.1.

I've Googled around and I can't seem to find a direct download for the 10.2.1 SDK anywhere, I am not even sure if you can get access to iOS SDKs that way.

Is there any way I can get 10.2.1 on a simulated device in Xcode 8.2.1/8.3 or is it simply not available without the "real" hardware?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode - Run Simulator with older iOS Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788426/xcode-run-simulator-with-older-ios-version)

Comment: As a note, minor revisions are not listed, so the closest to e.g. 10.2.x you'll get is 10.2

Comment: @xoudini - Thank you for your response. Do they have that in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: I don't think so, probably because it's sort of a non-issue – minor revisions of iOS don't alter features or functionality, so there shouldn't be a difference in app behaviour, barring very specific bugs.

Comment: @xoudini - Gotcha. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I'd have to check but my guess is we didn't release an SDK update for 10.2.1 because it only contained minor device-only fixes. We usually only release simulator runtime updates for major/minor versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS SDK v10.2.1 was never made available.