# IOS Swift - Search Ad API requestAttributionDetails Just returns Nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, apple-search-ads

im trying to uses Apples Search Ad api to return the ad data to the app so I can record it. The first attempt produced Apples default data,the next day im getting nil returned on all attributes.

would this have something to do with it? **iadAttribution = false**

Im testing on a few devices, one has been updated to the latest IOS, All produce the same result.

Please Not the app is not live yet, and im using testing devices!

Any ideas why its returning nil instead of the default data?

Iv been following this tutorial
http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-read-search-ads-attribution-api-information/

```
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        getSearchAdsInfo()
    }

 func getSearchAdsInfo(){
    ADClient.shared().requestAttributionDetails({ (attributionDetails, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    for (type, adDictionary) in attributionDetails! {
                        var attribution = adDictionary as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>;
                        let params = [
                            "deviceID": self.appData.deviceInfo,
                            "appID": "self.appData.appID",
                            "iadAdgroupId": attribution?["iad-adgroup-id"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadAdgroupName": attribution?["iad-adgroup-name"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadAttribution": attribution?["iad-attribution"] as? String  as Any,
                            "iadCampaignId": attribution?["iad-campaign-id"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadCampaignName": attribution?["iad-campaign-name"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadClickDate": attribution?["iad-click-date"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadConversionDate": attribution?["iad-conversion-date"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadCreativeId": attribution?["iad-creative-id"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadCreativeName": attribution?["iad-creative-name"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadKeyword": attribution?["iad-keyword"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadLineitemId": attribution?["iad-lineitem-id"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadLineitemName": attribution?["iad-lineitem-name"] as? String as Any,
                            "iadOrgName": attribution?["iad-org-name"] as? String as Any

                            ]
                      print(params)
                    }
                }
            })
}
```

And the result

```
    ["iadCampaignName": nil, 
    "iadLineitemName": nil, 
    "iadCreativeId": nil, 
    "iadOrgName": nil, 
    "iadConversionDate": nil, 
    "iadAdgroupName": nil, 
    "iadClickDate": nil, 
    "iadCreativeName": nil, 
    "iadLineitemId": nil, 
    "iadCampaignId": nil, 
    "iadKeyword": nil, 
    "iadAdgroupId": nil, 
    "iadAttribution": Optional("false")]
```

and print(attributionDetails) produces the following

```
Optional(["Version3.1": {
    "iad-attribution" = false;
}])
```

Comment: this casting is not correct can you print **attribution** and attach it

Comment: @Sh_Khan not 100% sure what you mean, but iv added the print log of the attributionDetails

Comment: if this the content of **attributionDetails** then how you query it for these keys

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry Im pretty new to IOS Development! So Im not totally clued up with the lingo! Im calling this as a function in the loadview on main ViewController

Comment: the dictionary has no values to the other keys so they are nil

Comment: @Sh_Khan Iv been using this  article as a reference http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-read-search-ads-attribution-api-information/

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is getting Simulator for iOS version 10.2. With this version dummy data is coming through. I got this:

```
`Optional([AnyHashable("Version3.1"): {
    "iad-adgroup-id" = 1234567890;
    "iad-adgroup-name" = AdGroupName;
    "iad-attribution" = true;
    "iad-campaign-id" = 1234567890;
    "iad-campaign-name" = CampaignName;
    "iad-click-date" = "2018-06-12T14:56:14Z";
    "iad-conversion-date" = "2018-06-12T14:56:14Z";
    "iad-creative-id" = 1234567890;
    "iad-creative-name" = CreativeName;
    "iad-keyword" = Keyword;
    "iad-lineitem-id" = 1234567890;
    "iad-lineitem-name" = LineName;
    "iad-org-name" = OrgName;
}])
```

It appears dummy data is not sent in the latest iOS version (in my case 11.4)

Follow this link to get see how to get simulator for older iOS version:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684633/1072262